# VBA Excel IE Automation - Control Dynamic Dropdown IE11

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation, dynamic-programming

I am attempting to access and change a dynamically created dropdown list on a webpage in IE11.  I don't seem to be setting the boxes to an object.

The HTML code does not show the actual dropdown, but only division where a script puts it:

```
<span id="valid_portOfUnlading" class="control-grop">
    <span class="span2"><label for="portOfUnladingCode">Port of Unlading</label></span>
    <span class="span2 span2-input"><div id="anchor_portOfUnlading" title="Port of Unlading"></div></span>
</span>
```

I have learned the form ID's and element ID's from getElementById.   The form ID for this dropdown element is "editEntryForm" or "manualEntryForm" (Not Sure which.)    The ID for the select box is "edit_portOfUnladingCode"  So far I have tried the following:

```
Set evt = myDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
Set lst = myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")
lst.selectedIndex = 6
lst.dispatchEvent evt

Set evt = myDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
Set lst = myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(0)
lst.selectedIndex = 6
lst.dispatchEvent evt

Set evt = myDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False
Set lst = myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(1)
lst.selectedIndex = 6
lst.dispatchEvent evt
```

And also ......

```
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode").Click
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(0).Click
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(1).Click


'   works on version 8 but not 9 or later apparently
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode").Focus
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode").selectedIndex = 6
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode").FireEvent ("onchange")

    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(0).Focus
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(0).selectedIndex = 6
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(0).FireEvent ("onchange")

    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(1).Focus
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(1).selectedIndex = 6
    myDoc.getElementById("edit_portOfUnladingCode")(1).FireEvent ("onchange")
```

I'm at my wits end.  Hoping a VBA automation guru can help me out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correction.  I AM able to set the select box(es) to an object and then return the current value.  But I am not able to click on the box(es) or change their value(s).  Do I need to somehow activate the division or span first, in order to get the inpout box to ;op up?  They all evaluate what you type in them and then the drop down list adjust to the letters that you type.  For example, if the user types "a" then all options with "a" will show on the list, etc, like google does.  But the value must be somewhere on the list in order to be validated.

Comment: Again, another correction.  I'm not familiar with how javascript is working to createe these select boxes on the html sheet, but I have found some different code for another javascript module pertaining to one of the dropdown boxes.

[code]
<script type="text/template" id="portOfEntryDropdown">
<select class="span2-input" id="<@=name@>" name="<@=name@>">
 <@ _.each(list, function(option) { @>
 <@ var optionText = option.cd; @>
  <option value="<@=option.cd@>"><@=optionText@></option>
 <@ }); @>
</select>
</script>
[/code]

Does this make sense to anyone?